# Delphi + android java class + init function

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Following my previous question ([Why I receive Invoke error: method not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53139487/why-i-receive-invoke-error-method-not-found)), I found a problem and want to make it as a new standalone question.

I have this class in Java:

```java
public class myClass {

  public static void init(String key, Context context) {}

}
```

And I have this code in Delphi:

```pascal
type
  JMyClassClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{2E91BB84-D9C9-4569-A687-BCB3684A8DBD}']
    {class} procedure init(key: JString; context: JContext); cdecl;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/myClass')]
  JMyClass = interface(JObject)
    ['{2761621D-63E1-4F57-964D-46FBE81DAB8B}']
  end;
  TJMyClass = class(TJavaGenericImport<JMyClassClass, JMyClass>) end;
```

When I do this in Delphi:

```java
TJMyClass.JavaClass.init(StringToJstring('toto'), TAndroidHelper.Context.getApplicationContext);
```

I will receive this error:

> Invoke error: method not found

**if I rename `init` to anything else** (like `initialize`, for example), it will work! But as it's not my library, I can not rename the function.

How can I call the `init` function from Delphi?

Comment: Embarcadero's JNIBridge framework uses its own `init()` methods for class constructors. If a class has an actual non-constructor `init()` method, there is likely a conflict within the framework's internal logic. You should [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero.

Comment: Can you not declare a descendant in Java code? I'm guessing you'd rather avoid that

Comment: @DaveNottage : yes it's what i did, ut it's a pity to create a new jar that wrap another jar just because it's impossible to bind in delphi a function named "init" :(

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's already reported, here: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-10150